# How to subtract quantity between two tables based on item types in Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, sql

Hi I have two tabels PURCHASE and DELIVERY where by I want to show the remaining quantity in another table 'STOCK'.
Below is the output I got from my STOCK table  and the code I did, but the calculation is wrong.
Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

```
private void stock(){  

        dbConection db = new dbConection();
        Connection con=db.getConnection();     
            String sql = "Select delivery.pro_Name, delivery.pro_Code, (sum(purchase.pur_qty) - sum(delivery.Qty)) AS bal from  delivery, purchase where purchase.productCode = delivery.pro_Code GROUP BY delivery.pro_Code ";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)stockTable.getModel();

            tm.setRowCount(0);
            while(rs.next()){

                Object o[]={rs.getString("pro_Code"), rs.getString("pro_Name"), rs.getString("bal")};
                tm.addRow(o);
            }


        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is only a SQL problem, and Java is only for view the results.
The above code will be for MS SQL Server, as you did not provide the type of SQL Database.

A final stock is calculated starting from an initial stock.
So you will must have something like:

```
initial_stock + purchase_qty - delivery_qty  = final_stock (group by ProductId)
```

Now, if you store your articles/products in your database as FIFO, that means you imply also the price in this formula, so group by implies also Fifo_Price . This could be also more complex SQL Select, based of related tables.

Supposing you don't need FIFO, but only a remaining quantity stock, the select syntax will be something like this:

```sql
-- Supposing initial stock is stored in Product Table
Select pr.ProductID, pr.InitialStock, Sum(IsNull(pc.Quantity,0)) AS QuantityIn,
    Sum(IsNull(dv.Quantity,0)) AS QuantityOut, 
    pr.InitialStock + sum(IsNull(pc.Quantity,0) - IsNull(dv.Quantity,0)) AS FinalStock
From Products pr
Left Join Purchase pc on pr.ProductID = pc.ProductID
Left Join Delivery dv on pr.ProductID = dv.ProductID
Group By pr.ProductID, pr.InitialStock

-- if you want to see only products that are implied in purchase and delivery tables, you must Inner Join all tables
```

Edit: I have deleted the rest of answer, because was not relevant to question.

**Edit 2:** Please look at this picture. I have made a simple test showing what are results as I did and as you did:

[image: Select statement]

Considering that initial stock is not null, I did not force a replacement with 0, but you can replace that too, so `st.qty` will be `IsNull(st.Qty, 0) as InitialStock`

Comment: Hi Vali, Thanks  for your detail explanation and the suggestions regarding the issues. I did created different table  and tried to apply your instructions. Still I am getting wrong about the remaining stock  
This the query I did try
Select pr.st_proCode, pr.st_Qty, Sum(pc.pur_qty) AS QuantityIn, Sum(dv.Qty) AS QuantityOut, 
(pr.st_Qty + sum(pc.pur_qty)) - sum(dv.Qty) AS FinalStock From stock 
Left Join purchase pc on pr.st_proCode = pc.productCode 
Left Join delivery2 dv on pr.st_proCode = dv.Pro_Code 
Group By pr.st_proCode, pr.st_Qty

Comment: you did not test for null... a value + null equals null... if left join does not find quantity for a table, in or out, the value will be replaced with null... as example, if you have product id with stock = 5, you don't have purchase, you have delivery 4, the final stock will not be 1, but will be null (5 + null - 4 = null). Because left join will replace the missing quantity_in of product id 1 with null. So your select is missing IsNull function: IsNull(pc.Pur_qty, 0), to replace the null value with 0.

Comment: Also, you don't need those parenthesis on FinalStock calculation, because `a + b - c = (a + b) - c = a + (b - c)`
Second 'Also': Try to maintain the same naming columns. If you named Id of Product as ProductID, go in all your foreign tables and rename it like this. Don't name them PrID in a table, ProdID in another one, IDProduct in other and so on.... It will be very difficult to write and to understand your own code ;)

Comment: check the answer, I have edited it and add a picture from my SSMS with a small test.

Comment: Hi Vali, you are just awesome. I have just done the final calculation in 10 minutes after seeing your latest reference solution. Please don't delete the comments, as they are really helpful to understand the logic. Thanks a lot 
 ![Here is the link for Stock output](https://ibb.co/2ZmBSny).

Comment: I will not remove any of the comments. One question: why do you use 3 tables to show separate types? I would use only one and add columns for each type of data I want to view: initial_stock, purchased, delivered, final_stock. And add event on double click to display a Register, each purchased and delivered record in those two tables for double clicked item, ordered by data ;) Cheers.